# java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage - How to handle exceptions?

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.concurrent

I'm trying to find better way to handle multiple exceptions in following code:

```
public CompletionStage<Result> getRepositoryInfo(String repositoryOwner, String repositoryName) {
return repositoryInfoService.getRepositoryInfo(repositoryOwner, repositoryName)
        .handle((repositoryInfo, ex) -> {
            if (repositoryInfo != null) {
                return ok(Json.toJson(repositoryInfo));
            } else {
                if (ex.getCause() instanceof GithubRepoNotFoundException) {
                    return notFound(Json.toJson("repo not found"));
                } else {
                    return internalServerError(Json.toJson("internal error"));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

This program gets github repo name and owner and returns some basic info (like full name, description, cloned url etc.).  `repositoryInfoService.getRepositoryInfo()` returns object or throws either `GithubRepoNotFoundException` or `GithubApiException`. This `instanceof` looks really ugly and I'm not happy with it. Another option is to `rethrow ex.getCause()` but it also sucks.

Comment: That’s way to broad. Besides that, you can simplify that lambda expression: `.handle((repositoryInfo, ex) -> repositoryInfo!=null? ok(Json.toJson(repositoryInfo)): ex.getCause() instanceof GithubRepoNotFoundException?  notFound(Json.toJson("repo not found")): internalServerError(Json.toJson("internal error")));` (imagine a better formatting than SO comments allow…)

Comment: The way you handle your exceptions depends on how you design your entire application. It makes no sense to tell you how to handle them at one particular asynchronous job. I’m quite sure that the three methods `ok`, `notFound` and `internalServerError` do basically the same and differ only in small aspects (e.g. the http status code they will send) which could be encapsulated in a parameter. So a redesign regarding these methods would allow entirely different (most probably, more elegant) ways to handle the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that provide more fluent API for `if` statements and `instanceof` in particular.

Using [javaslang matcher](http://www.javaslang.io/javaslang-docs/#_pattern_matching) and java's `Optional` your handler would look like

```
.handle((repositoryInfo, ex) -> ofNullable(repositoryInfo)
    .map(info -> ok(toJson(info)))
    .orElse(Match(ex.getCause()).of(
        Case(of(GithubRepoNotFoundException.class), notFound(toJson("repo not found")),
        Case(any(), internalServerError(toJson("internal error")))));
```